# Binary reader skips instructions

Tags: c#, breakpoints, binaryreader

I'm trying to read from a binary file with `BinaryReader`.

This is how I call my reading method :

```
         foreach (Movie film in TreeBuilder.myMovies)
        {
            if (File.Exists(@"C:\Users\DaPhunk\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\YLK\Binary\" + film.MovieName + ".txt"))
            {
                string[] myArray = operationManager.BinaryReading(film.MovieName);
                if (myArray != null)
                {
                    this.textStarring.Text = myArray[1];
                    this.textProduced.Text = myArray[2];
                    this.textMusic.Text = myArray[3];
                    this.textYear.Text = myArray[4];
                    this.textTime.Text = myArray[5];
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("An error occured");
                }
            }
```

This is my reading method :

```
                 public string[] BinaryReading(string name)
       {

            FileStream myStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\DaPhunk\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\YLK\Binary\" + name + ".txt", FileMode.Open);
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(myStream);

            string loadString = reader.ReadString();
            string[] loadArray = loadString.Split(',');

            reader.Close();
            myStream.Close();

            return loadArray;       

       }
```

Now something within these lines is not working. My file is not empty because since it's only a string I can read whats in the file.

My problem is I'm trying to find whats wrong with a break point but as soon as I get past this line :

```
         string loadString = reader.ReadString();
```

My program starts to run again. How is that possible ? This prevents me from checking what's inside my `String[]` and what are my values after the method call.

Any idea why ?  Thanks in advance.

---

Update :

I tried to move my `breakpoint` here

```
                 string[] loadArray = loadString.Split(',');
```

But my program never stops so it never gets past the previous line.

Also this is my Writting method :

```
           foreach (Movie film in TreeBuilder.myMovies)
        {
            if (film.MovieName == name)
            {
                FileStream myStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\DaPhunk\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\YLK\Binary\" + film.MovieName + ".txt", FileMode.Create);
                BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(myStream);

                writer.Write(film.MovieName + "," + starring + "," + produced + "," + music + "," + year + "," + lenght);
                writer.Close();
                myStream.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: My break point is on the first line (foreach condition)

Comment: (re comments on an answer); if you wrote the file with `BinaryWriter`, you should make that clear in the question, and you probably shouldn't call the file `.txt`.

Comment: Thanks that was the problem. I changed all my extensions for .bin and everything worked fine.
Just Write your comment as an answer so I can mark it as accepted.
Thanks a lot !

Comment: no, changing the extension won't suddently make it work if it wasn't working before - my only comment there was that a `.txt` file that isn't text could confuse both the maintenance programmer and the end-user.

Comment: Probably shouldn't be using binary readers and writers when actually just working with strings in the first place.

Comment: @MarcGravell Ok I see but the weird thing is it does work for some reason.. my `BreakPoint` gets past the line and what was supposed to be outputted early is now working... I don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string will be prefixed with a length field. That makes the `.txt` extension misleading.

Since it 'suddenly started working again' : is it possible you opened (and saved) one of the files with a Text editor?

Also, your current Read and Write methods are not thread-safe, you should enclose the Stream and Reader/Writer objects in `using() {}` statements.